# Raspberry Pi-Tools in Ubuntu Core?

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

Linux Distributions for the Raspberry Pi like Ubuntu oder Raspberry Pi OS (formerly Raspbian) usually come with the rpi-* and raspi-config to configure/enable the hardware and update the EEPROM and things like that.

In Ubuntu Core I did not see them, neither did I find a snap containing them.

What is the supposed way to configure and update the hardware unter Ubuntu Core?

Comment: I might post a full answer later, but there is [a raspi-config GitHub repo](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config), so that might help. I don't see any specific directions, but I might try figuring it out. Also, check out [Raspberry Pi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)